# IsAuthenticated not changing after logging in

Tags: jquery, wcf, web-services, rest, forms-authentication

I have a static HTML page that allows the user to log in and then call other web services to update content. The username and password are sent to a WCF REST service via JQuery. The login service looks like this:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST")]
public bool Login(ServiceUser user)
{
    if(validCredentials(user)){
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, true);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But before that happens, on page load I call another service to see if the user has already been authenticated. That service looks like this:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "isAuthenticated")]
public bool IsAuthenticated()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
}
```

That way, if they reload the page but have already logged in, I don't prompt them for their password again.

The problem is that IsAuthenticated doesn't seem to change it's value unless I close and reopen the browser. Refreshing the page doesn't change the value. Am I coding it wrong? Is it caching the value since it's a WebGet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I was right that WebGet was caching it. I changed the IsAuthenticated service to use [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "isAuthenticated", Method = "POST")] and it appears to be working correctly.